# How to use ValidateAntiForgeryToken at controller level in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, antiforgerytoken, coreclr

I have ASP.NET Core application. I have been using `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute on all `POST` action methods so far.

Now i am  thinking to use`ValidateAntiForgeryToken` at controller level so it can take care of both `POST` and `GET` methods.

Below is sample controller

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public class SearchController : Controller
{
    public SearchController()
    {
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {           
        return View();
    }      

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Save(MyModel model)
    {

    }
```

}

When user accesses the URL http://localhost/search, im not sure how `Index` action method will receive forgerytoken? Right now i get error `Bad Request` because there is no token included in the request.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/

**Limitations of the Anti-Forgery helpers**

> It only works with POST requests, not GET requests. Arguably this isn’t a limitation, because under the normal HTTP conventions, you shouldn’t be using GET requests for anything other than read-only operations.

<del>So it isn't useful at the controller level.</del>

**ASP.NET Core**

`[ValidateAntiforgeryToken]` on the controller has limitations.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-2.1

> ASP.NET Core doesn't support adding antiforgery tokens to GET requests automatically.

Controller-level support is improved with `[AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]`

> This attribute works identically to the ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute, except that it doesn't require tokens for requests made using the following HTTP methods:
>
> - GET
> - HEAD
> - OPTIONS
> - TRACE

Comment: I would say that it is still useful. When you add it on the controller level you don't need to add it to ALL post actions (less lines of code) and you don't risk of forgetting to put it on some post action.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include anti forgery token in your view.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Search", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    // Rest of html
}
```

That way when you do a post, the anti forgery token is then submitted along with the request.

Comment: My question was not related to POST. Its about GET